# how to fix property does not exit in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

so I'm working on existing code base and I'm trying make the mat-form filed to get TextData that written in mam-chart.model.ts file but some reason I'm getting this error " ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined' ". I

Any suggestion or help will be really apppreciated

design.ts

```
import { Chart, TextData, ChartData} from 'src/app/mam-chart/models';
export class ChartDesignComponent implements OnInit {
 chart: Chart;
 chartData: ChartData;
}
```

design.html

```
            <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                <mat-label>Text</mat-label>
                <input matInput  [(ngModel)]="chartData.textData.text" />
            </mat-form-field >

            <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                <mat-label>Color(# + hex color code)</mat-label>
                <input matInput [(ngModel)]="chartData.textData.color"/>
            </mat-form-field >
```

mam-chart.model.ts

```
export class Chart {
    id: number;
    chartType: ChartType = ChartType.chart;
    version: number = 2;
    dataType: ChartDataType = ChartDataType.static;
    template: ChartTemplate;

    .........

}
export class TextCard extends Chart {
    public chartData: CardDataChart;

    constructor(json?: any) {
        super(json)
        if (json == null) {
            return;
        }
        this.chartData = new ChartData(json.chartData);
    }
}


export class TextData {
    public text:  string;
    public color:  string;
    public size: string;
    public sizePx: number;

    constructor(json?: any) {
        if (json == null) {
            this.text = "";
            this.color = "";
            this.size = "";
            this.sizePx = 20;
            return;
        }
       ......

export class ChartData {
    filteredData: FilteredData[];
    figures: Figure[];
    textData: TextData;
}
```

Comment: Where do you instance the Chart  and ChartData in your component? There is only the property definition with those types

Comment: You need to write `this.chart = new Chart()` and `this.chartData = new ChartData(json)`; inside your  `ChartDesignComponent`. Either inside the constructor, or ngOnInit. Or you only need to use `chartData.textData.color` in the template. We need to see more of the `ChartDesignComponent` to help out

Comment: @AlanGrosz Hi, I'm not sure what you mean but I added a few code, can you please check it out again. thanks

Answer (score 0):

your class Chart hasn't property chartData and textData too...
try so `[(ngModel)]="chartData.textData.color"`

Comment: Hi I did chartData2 : ChartDataChart in my design.ts file and [(ngModel)]="chartData2.textData.size" in my HTML file but I got this error in my chrome console " ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'textData' of undefined ". by anychance do you know what this errors is about. thanks

Comment: This error say about that chartData2 is undefined. You need create instance of ChartDataChart for chartData2 and then you can bind chartData2.textData.size field

Comment: Hi again, I did just like the first on [(ngModel)]="chartData.textData.color" but now I got " Cannot read property 'text' of ". I know that I have this textData = TextData inside my ChartData but I'm not sure why it saying it can't read.